# Lagrange multipliers and angle between vectors

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Can someone please help me with solving this question? I'm new to learning this and I'm not at all sure if what i've done is correct...

The question is: the plane $4x-3y+8z=5$ intersects the cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$in an ellipse. Let $P$ and $Q$ be the highest and lowest points on the ellipse. If $O$ denotes the origin, what is the angle between $ \overrightarrow{OP}$ and $ \overrightarrow{OQ}$  vectors?

so to find P and Q, if

$f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$,

$ g_{1} (x,y,z)=4x-3y+8z-5=0,$

$ g_{2} (x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z^2=0$

then $2x=4 \lambda +2x \mu, 2y=-3 \lambda +2y \mu ,2z=8 \lambda -2z \mu  $.

from $2x=4 \lambda +2x \mu$ and $ 2y=-3 \lambda +2y \mu $, I got $(1- \mu)= \frac{4 \lambda }{2x} =\frac{-3 \lambda }{2y}$ so $x= \frac{-4}{3} y$.... Am I on the right track?

so applying this value to $g_{1}$ equals $-25y+24z=15$ and to $g_{2}$ equals $y^2=\frac{9}{25} z^2$, and I got $y=\pm \frac{3}{5}z$.

If $y=\frac{3}{5}z$, i got $z=\frac{5}{3}, y=1, x=-\frac{4}{3}$, and if $y=-\frac{3}{5}z$, i got  $z=\frac{5}{13}, y=-\frac{3}{13}, x=\frac{4}{13}$

So... i guess P is $(-\frac{4}{3},1,\frac{5}{3})$ and Q is $(\frac{4}{13},-\frac{3}{13},\frac{5}{13})$

$\overrightarrow{OP}:-\frac{4}{3}i + j + \frac{5}{3}k$ and $\overrightarrow{OQ}=\frac{4}{13}i-\frac{3}{13}j+\frac{5}{13}k$

and $\overrightarrow{OP}\bullet \overrightarrow{OQ} = \frac{6}{13} $, $\sqrt{ \overrightarrow{OP} }= \sqrt{50/9},\sqrt{ \overrightarrow{OQ} }= \sqrt{50/169} $. so i guess the angle would be $cos^{-1}(9/25)$.....

I can't use calculators to solve the value for cos, so I'm a bit doubtful for the answer I've got.

Comment: Not sure the question is entirely clear, but if they are asking for the "highest" and "lowest" points, I should think you want to maximise and minimise $f(x,y,z)=z$, not $x^2+y^2+z^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a trick question ? Wont the highest and lowest points be diametrically opposite, so shouldent the angle be  $90^{\circ}$ ?